# Why would the naive definition of moving average cause unnecessary locking in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

The TensorFlow [docs for tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#moving-averages) say,

> When you run the ops to maintain the moving averages, each shadow
>   variable is updated with the formula:
>
> shadow_variable -= (1 - decay) * (shadow_variable - variable)
>
> This is mathematically equivalent to the classic formula below, but
>   the use of an assign_sub op (the "-=" in the formula) allows
>   concurrent lockless updates to the variables:
>
> shadow_variable = decay * shadow_variable + (1 - decay) * variable

Why does the first formula permit more concurrency than the second formula?  How can I know if my own code is incurring unnecessary locking because of some subtle locking issue?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you start `shadow_variable=` update in multiple threads in parallel at the same time. After threads finish, `shadow_variable` will get the value computed by the slowest thread, so computation by other threads is wasted. To prevent this, you could introduce some kind of locking mechanism, or use the `-=` version

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain this in more depth?  Unfortunately I am still just as confused as I was.  Both statements have shadow_variable and variable each occurring once on the RHS, so why is there a relevant difference?

Comment: It's like i++ vs i=i+1, if you execute the later update several times in parallel, only one update gets applied

Comment: Sorry, I am still really confused.  Why would you have multiple threads updating shadow_variable in the first place?  Nothing I have done with TensorFlow so far has involved multiple threads (unless it is going on behind the scenes).  And if you did have multiple updaters, couldn't you still have non-serializable behavior even if "-=" is atomic?  (In C, by the way, there is no semantic difference between i++ and i=i+1 -- neither is guaranteed atomic.)

Comment: Also, your answer made me think that the issue was just that using the second formula would be less efficient (you say that computation by other threads is "wasted").  Now it sounds like you are saying the problem is the second formula can give the wrong answer?

Comment: imagine if your i++ was atomic and i=i+1 was not atomic. Then doing the first version in parallel k-ways would increment by k (concurrent lockless update), but the second version would increment by 1 (incorrect result with concurrent lockless updates)